# Clear the other persons inventory when they die?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing with my friend, and I want to create a PVP arena. I have built it and added a screen to tell you when to start, and also give you your PVP items, so I am trying to clear the other person's inventory so they don't spawn kill the other person. Please help! To be clear, I need to clear the **killer's** inventory not the one who dies.

Comment: Can you post what commands you have tried to achieve this? Asking us for a solution without posting what you've tried usually gives negative responses.

Comment: You may want to specify that you want the killer to die in the post as this was unclear to me. Also, does this need to work for 3+ players or just 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 'dead' to lose their items... you could put 'keep inventory' off.

If you want the winner to not be able to simply loot the deat, put 'keep inventory' on.

If you want people to not drop their inventory on the ground, but still start with a blank inventory when respawning, then you might want to look into the Minecraft command line.

Comment: Oh wait, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: If you downvoted this, I know it doesn't clear the inventory, but, it gets the job done. That because they still have the armour so they still can fight. And, the other person can't get more armour

Comment: To be clear, you wanted to "clear the **killer's** inventory not the one who dies." If so, how is this a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

Put a pressure plate at spawn that `/clear @p[rm=6]` them.

Comment: Sorry, but putting a pressure plate won't work because we want to clear the inventory of the other person, not the who died.

Comment: @ArjunRawat then use `@p[rm=6]` instead as this will then target the nearest person at least 6 blocks away.

Comment: Yes, that would 100% work. Thank you!